# What happen if I try to use SetObject and I already had the same key?

Tags: cachingframework.redis

I'm working on a project using Redis cache with cachingFramework.redis.

I already have working the get function with Redis (using FetchObject)

but I need to update the Save function to save in DB and override/update the key/value in Redis.

Should I use SetObject? or I need to call first Remove(key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the `when` parameter, but by default the SET operation on redis overrides the current value, regardless of its type. [Here](https://redis.io/commands/set) is the documentation.

So you don't need to call the `Remove` method.

You can check [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/src/StackExchange.Redis/RedisDatabase.cs#L3424) how `StackExchange.Redis` library choose between different SET commands (SET, SETNX, SETEX) depending on the parameters.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Yeah, I already was seen the documentation but cachingFramework.redis documentation is pretty poor. And it don't say anything about send specific commands. but I tested and works as you said. SetObject override the current value with the same key.